# Check_MK 'Global Settings' error

Tags: check-mk

I have installed OMD with Check_MK yesterday and everything worked fine. Now when I go to the Check_MK web UI and click on the Global Settings I am getting an error saying: Error running Check_MK --automation get-configuration --. Invalid output from web service (unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 0)):

It doesn't have any references where I could look into or something. Could someone please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. If others will encounter the same problem as I did, the reason was that I have copied couple of check_mk plugin files however, one of them wasn't properly read by OMD, so I had to delete it and everything worked as it should.